# Proving $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2\sqrt{2}\Gamma(\frac{n+3}{2})}{n^{3/2}\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})} =1$

Tags: combinatorics, limits, gamma-function

> Assume $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Using Wolfram Alpha I found that the following has a nice limit:
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2\sqrt{2}\cdot\Gamma(\frac{n+3}{2})}{n^{3/2}\cdot\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})} =1
> \end{align*}
> $$
> However, I'm not really sure how to arrive to that result through half-integer gamma.

From what [I'm gathering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#Integers_and_half-integers),

$$
\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+3}{2})}{\Gamma(n/2)} = 2^{-3/2}\frac{(n+1)!!}{(n-2)!!}
$$
which, I can only guess, should evaluate at $2^{-3/2} n^{3/2}$ or something close, but [cannot see why](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28n%2B1%29%21%21%2F%28n-2%29%21%21).

Comment: Did you try the functional equation of the $\Gamma$ function?

Comment: Consequence of $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\Gamma(x+a)}{x^a\Gamma(x)}=1$ for any $a$, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3980277).

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain, @ metamorphy Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to other methods, using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation),

$$\operatorname{\Gamma}(n+1)=n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n$$

you have

$$\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{n+3}2\right)\sim\sqrt{\pi(n+3)}\left(\frac{n+3}{2e}\right)^{\frac{n+3}2}\\
\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac n2\right)\sim\sqrt{\pi n}\left(\frac n{2e}\right)^{\frac n2}$$

and in the limit,

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\sqrt2\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{n+3}2\right)}{n^{\frac32}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac n2\right)}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\sqrt2\sqrt{\pi(n+3)}\left(\frac{n+3}{2e}\right)^{\frac{n+3}2}}{n^{\frac32}\sqrt{\pi n}\left(\frac n{2e}\right)^{\frac n2}}\\[1ex]
&=\frac{2\sqrt2}{(2e)^{\frac32}}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+3}n\right)^{\frac{n+3}2}\\[1ex]
\end{align}$$

and $\left(\frac{n+3}n\right)^{\frac{n+3}2}\to e^{\frac32}$, so the limit of $1$ follows.

Comment: Both yours and @metamorphy linked one are very interesting approaches, learned new tricks today, thanks!