# Gamma functions approaches solely n to a negative power

Tags: asymptotics, power-series, approximation, gamma-function

I have read $[x^n] (1-x)^\alpha\sim \frac{n^{-\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(-\alpha)}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ where $[x^n]$ means coefficient of $x^n$ in what follows.
But I have never seen a proof of this assuming can take the symbol $\sim$ to also mean approximately or approaches but I have yet to see any proof. By letting $\alpha \rightarrow -\alpha$ in a series formula I have verified, I use $$(1-x)^\alpha=
\frac{1}{\Gamma(-\alpha)} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{n!}x^n,|x|<1$$
So this and the above implies $\frac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{n!}\rightarrow n^{-\alpha-1}
,n\rightarrow\infty$ And I certainly cannot reconcile this. So what is the discrepancy ? Is it an error in the text where I read this ?

Comment: Isn't the coefficient of $x^n$ really $\frac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{n!\Gamma(-\alpha)}$ because of the multiplier out front?

Comment: yes that is what i wrote

Comment: I never said it wasn't

Comment: and who is mpw that also would not let me put in the correct title

Comment: what I read said it was $\sim \frac {n^{-1-\alpha}}{\Gamma(-\alpha)}$

Comment: I don't mean that is exactly what I wrote but the power series implies that. So what is your point ?

Comment: the correct title is 'Discrepancy in that as n approaches inf gives a ratio of $\Gamma $ functions approaches solely n to a negative power.' and who is this mpw who put in the wrong title and would not let me put in the correct one ?

Comment: You are asking (I think?) how to derive the Stirling series. One way is to use the integral representation of $\Gamma$ and use Laplace's method to approximate the integral for $n \to \infty$

Comment: NO i am not asking that at all. Clearly as written I'm asking to prove $\Gamma(n-\alpha)/n!\rightarrow n^{-1-\alpha}$ as n goes to inf. OR else it is a text error what I read and it's not true. But now I have put in some representative numerical values eg. n:160,$\alpha:1/3,1/2,4/3$ or the negative of these in Maxima and in all 6 cases the |relative error| turned out to be <.01 so I guess it's not a text error and true but have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: NOw also I used the lowest order Stirling approximation for$ \frac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{n!}$ and get $\exp(\alpha+1)(n+1)^{-n-1/2} (n-\alpha)^{n-\alpha-1/2}$ and using this expression call it $t$ obtain the same low |relative difference| being $|\frac{t-n^{-\alpha-1}}{n^{-\alpha-1}}|<.01$ for those same 6 trial numeric values as prior comment. Someone remarked use integral representation to prove it. Can anyone explain that in some detail for this problem ?

Comment: Because otherwise especially with that exponential term $\exp(\alpha+1)$ how on earth it could possibly be true.

Comment: I changed the title because what you wrote was improper MathJax. You wrote `\Gamma$`   which appears exactly as typed (with backslash and single dollar sign). If you really want a capital Greek gamma ($\Gamma$), just change it to `$\Gamma$`. For what it's worth, one usually speaks of either "the Gamma function" or "$\Gamma$", but not usually "the $\Gamma$ function". Of course, you can put whatever you want.

Comment: Okay so much for the title,which perhaps better written as Ratio of gamma fct's.... as now I am almost sure $\frac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{n!}\rightarrow n^{-\alpha-1}$ as n goes to infinity so it's not a discrepancy . I just need someone to prove it and it is likely similar or uses some of the same ideas as Stirlings derivation or approximation for n! as n becomes very large.

Comment: Suppose $\alpha$ were integer then $ \frac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{n!}=\frac{(n-\alpha-1)!}{n!}$ which if $\alpha>-1$ is equal $\frac1{n(n-1)...(n-\alpha)}\rightarrow n^{-1-\alpha}\;as\;n\rightarrow\infty$. If $\alpha=-1\;then\;\frac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{n!}=\frac{n!}{n!}=n^{0}=1$!. If $\alpha<-1$ is equal
$(n-\alpha-1)(n-\alpha-2)...(n+1)\rightarrow n^{-1-\alpha}\;as\;n\rightarrow\infty$. If $\alpha$ were not an integer then intuitively linearly interpolate between the answers for that of the integer just above and that for the integer just below $\alpha$. Ofcourse this is not a rigorous proof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\Gamma(x+a)}{x^a\Gamma(x)}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980277/proving-lim-x-to-infty-frac-gammaxaxa-gammax-1) (stated for $a>0$ there, but holds for any $a\in\mathbb{C}$; actually used here [many times](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5CGamma(x%2Ba)%7D%7Bx%5Ea%5CGamma(x)%7D%3D1%24&p=1), and stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function))

Comment: with regard to that last comment by metamorphy  i think it may answer question. I just need more time to decipher thru it  but right now have a vision problem which should hopefully be ok in a few days but not entirely sure when i will be well. thanks and will get back to you